# Compute $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}} ( \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I think this question could be a little idiot, however I could not solve this after some hours. I need to find all homomorphism between the additive group $\mathbb{Q}$ and the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}  ( \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z})$. I tried to find a good set of generators for $\mathbb{Q}$, however none of them  satisfied a general homomorphism.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let $\varphi: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ suppose that $\varphi$ is non-trivial. Let $n$ be the smallest positive integer in $\mathrm{im}\; \varphi$. Pick $a/b \in \varphi^{-1}(n)$. Then

$$n=\varphi(a/b)=\varphi(a/2b+a/2b)=\varphi(a/2b)+\varphi(a/2b),$$

so $\varphi(a/2b)=n/2$, but this is impossible because $n$ was the smallest positive integer in the image. Thereby no non-trivial homomorphisms exist.

Answer (score 9):

$\,\Bbb Q\,$ is a [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) , so is any of its homomorphic images. But $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is *not* a divisible group (why?) , so it must be that the image of *any* group homomorphism  $\,\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z\,$ is the trivial subgroup (which, BTW, is the only finite group which is divisible and the only subgroup of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ that is divisible), and thus $\,\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Q,\Bbb Z)=0\,$

Comment: "But $\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* a divisible group, so it must by that the image of *any* group homomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial subgroup".  If you replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ you can see that there is a gap in your reasoning.  You want: more than just that $\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* divisible, $\mathbb{Z}$ has no nonzero divisible subgroup (a **reduced abelian group**).  Of course the "(why?)" equally well covers this, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks @PeteL.Clark, I think you're right. The correct, *complete*  argument must be that the only subgroup of the integers that is divisible is the trivial one, though this certainly is contained in the fact that all the subgroups of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ with more than one element are isomorphic with $\,\Bbb Z\,$ ...